# How to run a photo slideshow without a window manager

Tags: server, 20.04, xorg

I am currently trying to set up a photo slideshow on Ubuntu Server 20.04. At present, I am using `awesome` to set up the window manager and run

```
$ feh -zsrZFD 5 ~/Picture
```

However, my machine's performance is pretty poor (J1900 + 2G RAM). Is there a way that I can run the `feh` command without a window manager like `awesome`?

Comment: I think you need at least a window manager (which has a smaller footprint than a whole desktop environmen). But you can also explore extremely light-weight linux distros like Puppy Linux and Tiny Core. If you can use feh or some other program in such a distro, it will probably be more responsive. Other wise you can try to reduce the footprint of the pictures (lower resolution, easier to display image format) or simply reduce the resolution of the monitor (with xrandr or similar). Finally, you may find a used computer with better specs for free or a very low cost.

Comment: You could run the slideshow directly on the X-server without any window manager. However, the performance essentially will be equally poor: a light WM will not make for an appreciable decrease in performance.

Comment: @vanadium All right, I will stick to `awesome` then.